# How to send more than one packet of data from AWS IoT Core's MQTT Test Client to an AWS Dynamo DB Table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I have been able to populate one 'item' in the Dynamo DB table I have created.

To my understanding the code must be at least a bit functional since I was able to send some data, however, I am sending the same thing over and over again. So this leaves me confused as to why it will not store multiple 'items' over and over.

To be fair, I am new to this topic so I will also share a screenshot of the 'item' I am talking about:
['item'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc9oB.png)

I am unsure of what to try besides following tutorials online. I have followed a few, and suddenly after many fruitless attempts at getting anything to populate at all, one item was populated. But nothing else was populated even though the exact same code is looped through over and over.